# Mapping of an array of string Ids using lookup in MongoDB not working in Sails.js

Tags: aggregate, sails.js, lookup

**Sails.js >> Collection : Blog, BlogCategory.
Blog collection has an array of categories id as string value. I want all blog data with populate categories. Bellow query work fine in NoSqlBooster but not work in code.**

My Blog collection with categories array :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("64882e5fa368071ab81fd207"),
    "title" : "This is a test blog",
    "description" : "Demo test description",
    "categories" : [ "64882c8d6c7fc0561c0c129d", "64882c2d6c7fc0561c0c129c" ]
}
```

**I was tried both bellow code but it return empty categories array =  "categories": []**

```
   ` [{
      $project: {
        _id: 1,
        title: 1,
        description: 1,
        categories: {
          $map: {
            input: "$categories",
            as: "category",
            in: {
              $convert: {
                input: "$$category",
                to: "objectId", 
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "BlogCategory",
        localField: "categories",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "categories"
      }
    }]`
```

This one also work in NoSqlBooster but not in code..

```
{
            $lookup:
                {
                    from: "BlogCategory",
                    let: { catid: "$categories" },
                    pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match: {
                                $expr: {
                                    $in: ["$_id", {
                                        $map: {
                                            input: "$$catid",
                                            in: { $toObjectId: "$$this" }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    as: "categories"
                }
            }
```